# How to pass arguments into custom Redux middleware?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-middleware

I want to pass an argument into a custom Redux middleware.
But I don't know how to use the argument inside the custom middleware.

Example:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';

const customMiddleWare = store => next => action => {
  // how to use argument here?
};

const middlewares = [customMiddleWare(argument)];

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
);
```

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish? You're already passing an argument into `customMiddleWare` but it's not the one you think you are. Not sure what your actual use-case is, but in general, that's not how middleware is structured.

Comment: @DaveNewton You're right, I updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As middlewares are functions you can make a wrapper function that will take your argument and return your middleware function which will have access to the provided argument.

Example:

```
const middlewareWrapper = customArgument => store => next => action =>
  console.log(customArgument);
}

const middlewares = [middlewareWrapper(argument)];

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
);
```